# How to extract pattern tuples from a list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, data-structures, pattern-matching

I have the following list:

```
data = [('Mr', 'PROPN'), ('.', 'PUNCT'), ('William', 'PROPN'), ('Henry', 'PROPN'), ('Gates', 'PROPN'), (',', 'PUNCT'), ('III', 'NUM'), ('is', 'VERB'), ('Founder', 'PROPN'), ('and', 'CONJ'), ('Technology', 'PROPN'), ('Advisor', 'NOUN'), ('Director', 'NOUN'), ('of', 'ADP'), ('Microsoft', 'PROPN'), ('Corporation', 'PROPN'), ('a', 'DET'), ('cofounder', 'NOUN'), ('served', 'VERB'), ('as', 'ADP'), ('Chairman', 'PROPN'), ('from', 'ADP'), ('our', 'PRON'), ('incorporation', 'NOUN'), ('in', 'ADP'), ('1981', 'NUM'), ('until', 'ADP'), ('2014', 'NUM'), ('He', 'PRON'), ('currently', 'ADV'), ('acts', 'VERB'), ('Technical', 'ADJ'), ('to', 'ADP'), ('Nadella', 'NUM'), ('on', 'ADP'), ('key', 'ADJ'), ('development', 'NOUN'), ('projects', 'NOUN'), ('retired', 'VERB'), ('an', 'DET'), ('employee', 'NOUN'), ('2008', 'NUM'), ('Chief', 'NOUN'), ('Software', 'PROPN'), ('Architect', 'PROPN'), ('2000', 'NUM'), ('2006', 'NUM'), ('when', 'ADV'), ('he', 'PRON'), ('announced', 'VERB'), ('his', 'PRON'), ('two', 'NUM'), ('-', 'PUNCT'), ('year', 'NOUN'), ('plan', 'NOUN'), ('transition', 'VERB'), ('out', 'ADP'), ('day', 'NOUN'), ('full', 'ADJ'), ('time', 'NOUN'), ('role', 'NOUN'), ('Executive', 'PROPN'), ('Officer', 'PROPN'), ('resigned', 'VERB'), ('assumed', 'VERB'), ('the', 'DET'), ('position', 'NOUN'), ('As', 'ADP'), ('co', 'PROPN'), ('chair', 'NOUN'), ('Bill', 'NOUN'), ('&', 'CONJ'), ('Melinda', 'PROPN'), ('Foundation', 'PROPN'), ('shapes', 'NOUN'), ('approves', 'VERB'), ('grant', 'NOUN'), ('making', 'VERB'), ('strategies', 'NOUN'), ('advocates', 'NOUN'), ('for', 'ADP'), ('foundation’s', 'NUM'), ('issues', 'NOUN'), ('helps', 'VERB'), ('set', 'VERB'), ('overall', 'ADJ'), ('direction', 'NOUN'), ('organization', 'NOUN'), ('founder', 'NOUN'), ('’', 'NUM'), ('foresight', 'NOUN'), ('vision', 'NOUN'), ('personal', 'ADJ'), ('computing', 'NOUN'), ('have', 'AUX'), ('been', 'VERB'), ('central', 'ADJ'), ('success', 'NOUN'), ('software', 'NOUN'), ('industry', 'NOUN'), ('has', 'VERB'), ('unparalleled', 'ADJ'), ('knowledge', 'NOUN'), ('Company’s', 'NUM'), ('history', 'NOUN'), ('technologies', 'NOUN'), ('Company', 'NOUN'), ('its', 'PRON'), ('grew', 'VERB'), ('fledgling', 'ADJ'), ('business', 'NOUN'), ('into', 'ADP'), ('world’s', 'NUM'), ('leading', 'VERB'), ('company', 'NOUN'), ('process', 'NOUN'), ('creating', 'VERB'), ('one', 'NUM'), ('most', 'ADV'), ('prolific', 'ADJ'), ('sources', 'NOUN'), ('innovation', 'NOUN'), ('powerful', 'ADJ'), ('brands', 'NOUN'), ('through', 'ADP'), ('motion', 'NOUN'), ('technological', 'ADJ'), ('strategic', 'ADJ'), ('programs', 'NOUN'), ('that', 'DET'), ('are', 'VERB'), ('core', 'NOUN'), ('part', 'NOUN'), ('continues', 'VERB'), ('provide', 'VERB'), ('technical', 'ADJ'), ('input', 'NOUN'), ('evolution', 'NOUN'), ('productivity', 'NOUN'), ('platform', 'NOUN'), ('mobile', 'NOUN'), ('first', 'ADJ'), ('cloud', 'NOUN'), ('world', 'NOUN'), ('His', 'PRON'), ('work', 'NOUN'), ('overseeing', 'VERB'), ('provides', 'VERB'), ('global', 'ADJ'), ('insights', 'NOUN'), ('relevant', 'ADJ'), ('current', 'ADJ'), ('future', 'ADJ'), ('opportunities', 'NOUN'), ('keen', 'ADJ'), ('appreciation', 'NOUN'), ('stakeholder', 'ADJ'), ('interests', 'NOUN')]
```

I would like to extract triple patterns considering the second element of each tuple. For example, let's say I would like to extract all the tuples that has `'of'` between tuples that has a second element `'NOUN'` and `'PROPN'`:

```
[('Director', 'NOUN'), ('of', 'ADP'), ('Microsoft', 'PROPN')]
```

Hence, my question is how can I extract the above pattern without using regex?. The reason I do not want to use regex is because, I am going to start extracting tuples in more different ways. for instance, the tuples that has as a first value `'world’s'` followed by `'VERB'`, `'NOUN'`:

```
[('world’s', 'NUM'), ('leading', 'VERB'), ('company', 'NOUN')]
```

Comment: Why without regex?

Comment: Because sometimes writing the regex just makes more difficult this pattern extraction task @ElliotRoberts

Comment: If there are multiple, what should be done?

Comment: @ElliotRoberts, thanks for the help, return them into a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relatively fast, but probably unnecessarily compact solution:

```
from itertools import chain

# Generator of three-tuples matching requirements:
# If `data` is large enough that temp `list`s are a problem, might be worth
# using itertools.islice instead of shallow copy slices
# or using enumerate with lookaround indexing
matchtups = (((wd0, tp0), (wd1, tp1), (wd2, tp2))
             for (wd0, tp0), (wd1, tp1), (wd2, tp2) in zip(data, data[1:], data[2:])
             if wd1 == 'of' and tp0 == 'NOUN' and tp2 == 'PROPN')

# Flatten out the three-tuple structure:
results = list(chain.from_iterable(matchtups))
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the most useful. What about using something like a lexer or parser?... which method do you think is the best for doing this task?

Comment: Also, what about if there are more patterns like `[('Director', 'NOUN'), ('of', 'ADP'), ('Microsoft', 'PROPN')]`?. Is this approach robust enogh to also catch them?.

Comment: @johndoe: I mean, if it has two sets, they'll all appear in a flat list, one set of matches after another (the generator expression produces discrete three-tuples, but I unpacked them to match your question's requested output).

Comment: How to do it in a nested list in order to get the `n` patterns?.

Comment: @johndoe: I have no idea what you're asking. It's far too vague to answer.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear... What I meant to say was that consider that in my list of tuples I have the following pattern: `[('Director', 'NOUN'), ('of', 'ADP'), ('Microsoft', 'PROPN'), ('president', 'NOUN'), ('of', 'ADP'), ('google', 'PROPN')]`. With your above procedure, how can I extract the pattern into a nested list?: `[[('Director', 'NOUN'), ('of', 'ADP'), ('Microsoft', 'PROPN')],  [('president', 'NOUN'), ('of', 'ADP'), ('google', 'PROPN')]]`

Comment: Yeah, just don't do the second step with `chain` and you've got a generator that will produce tuples of tuples. You could make it a generator of lists of tuples by changing what it produces from `((wd0, tp0), (wd1, tp1), (wd2, tp2))` to `[(wd0, tp0), (wd1, tp1), (wd2, tp2)]`, and make it produce the final `list` directly by changing the outermost parens to brackets (making it a listcomp, rather than a genexpr). I only made it a genexpr to avoid the intermediate `list`, but if the `chain` step isn't needed, it can be a listcomp with no loss.

Answer (score 1):

you can loop over it with:

```
data = [('Mr', 'PROPN'), ('.', 'PUNCT'), ('William', 'PROPN'), ('Henry', 'PROPN'), ('Gates', 'PROPN'), (',', 'PUNCT'), ('III', 'NUM'), ('is', 'VERB'), ('Founder', 'PROPN'), ('and', 'CONJ'), ('Technology', 'PROPN'), ('Advisor', 'NOUN'), ('Director', 'NOUN'), ('of', 'ADP'), ('Microsoft', 'PROPN'), ('Corporation', 'PROPN'), ('a', 'DET'), ('cofounder', 'NOUN'), ('served', 'VERB'), ('as', 'ADP'), ('Chairman', 'PROPN'), ('from', 'ADP'), ('our', 'PRON'), ('incorporation', 'NOUN'), ('in', 'ADP'), ('1981', 'NUM'), ('until', 'ADP'), ('2014', 'NUM'), ('He', 'PRON'), ('currently', 'ADV'), ('acts', 'VERB'), ('Technical', 'ADJ'), ('to', 'ADP'), ('Nadella', 'NUM'), ('on', 'ADP'), ('key', 'ADJ'), ('development', 'NOUN'), ('projects', 'NOUN'), ('retired', 'VERB'), ('an', 'DET'), ('employee', 'NOUN'), ('2008', 'NUM'), ('Chief', 'NOUN'), ('Software', 'PROPN'), ('Architect', 'PROPN'), ('2000', 'NUM'), ('2006', 'NUM'), ('when', 'ADV'), ('he', 'PRON'), ('announced', 'VERB'), ('his', 'PRON'), ('two', 'NUM'), ('-', 'PUNCT'), ('year', 'NOUN'), ('plan', 'NOUN'), ('transition', 'VERB'), ('out', 'ADP'), ('day', 'NOUN'), ('full', 'ADJ'), ('time', 'NOUN'), ('role', 'NOUN'), ('Executive', 'PROPN'), ('Officer', 'PROPN'), ('resigned', 'VERB'), ('assumed', 'VERB'), ('the', 'DET'), ('position', 'NOUN'), ('As', 'ADP'), ('co', 'PROPN'), ('chair', 'NOUN'), ('Bill', 'NOUN'), ('&', 'CONJ'), ('Melinda', 'PROPN'), ('Foundation', 'PROPN'), ('shapes', 'NOUN'), ('approves', 'VERB'), ('grant', 'NOUN'), ('making', 'VERB'), ('strategies', 'NOUN'), ('advocates', 'NOUN'), ('for', 'ADP'), ('foundation’s', 'NUM'), ('issues', 'NOUN'), ('helps', 'VERB'), ('set', 'VERB'), ('overall', 'ADJ'), ('direction', 'NOUN'), ('organization', 'NOUN'), ('founder', 'NOUN'), ('’', 'NUM'), ('foresight', 'NOUN'), ('vision', 'NOUN'), ('personal', 'ADJ'), ('computing', 'NOUN'), ('have', 'AUX'), ('been', 'VERB'), ('central', 'ADJ'), ('success', 'NOUN'), ('software', 'NOUN'), ('industry', 'NOUN'), ('has', 'VERB'), ('unparalleled', 'ADJ'), ('knowledge', 'NOUN'), ('Company’s', 'NUM'), ('history', 'NOUN'), ('technologies', 'NOUN'), ('Company', 'NOUN'), ('its', 'PRON'), ('grew', 'VERB'), ('fledgling', 'ADJ'), ('business', 'NOUN'), ('into', 'ADP'), ('world’s', 'NUM'), ('leading', 'VERB'), ('company', 'NOUN'), ('process', 'NOUN'), ('creating', 'VERB'), ('one', 'NUM'), ('most', 'ADV'), ('prolific', 'ADJ'), ('sources', 'NOUN'), ('innovation', 'NOUN'), ('powerful', 'ADJ'), ('brands', 'NOUN'), ('through', 'ADP'), ('motion', 'NOUN'), ('technological', 'ADJ'), ('strategic', 'ADJ'), ('programs', 'NOUN'), ('that', 'DET'), ('are', 'VERB'), ('core', 'NOUN'), ('part', 'NOUN'), ('continues', 'VERB'), ('provide', 'VERB'), ('technical', 'ADJ'), ('input', 'NOUN'), ('evolution', 'NOUN'), ('productivity', 'NOUN'), ('platform', 'NOUN'), ('mobile', 'NOUN'), ('first', 'ADJ'), ('cloud', 'NOUN'), ('world', 'NOUN'), ('His', 'PRON'), ('work', 'NOUN'), ('overseeing', 'VERB'), ('provides', 'VERB'), ('global', 'ADJ'), ('insights', 'NOUN'), ('relevant', 'ADJ'), ('current', 'ADJ'), ('future', 'ADJ'), ('opportunities', 'NOUN'), ('keen', 'ADJ'), ('appreciation', 'NOUN'), ('stakeholder', 'ADJ'), ('interests', 'NOUN')]
[(x,y) for x,y in data if ('NOUN' == y) or ('PROPN' in y)]
```

I put in 2 ways to evaluate the if in the one above so you can pick.
You can also query using a more powerful syntax by converting it to a [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/).  This helps with more complex queries using a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [('Mr', 'PROPN'), ('.', 'PUNCT'), ('William', 'PROPN'), ('Henry', 'PROPN'), ('Gates', 'PROPN'), (',', 'PUNCT'), ('III', 'NUM'), ('is', 'VERB'), ('Founder', 'PROPN'), ('and', 'CONJ'), ('Technology', 'PROPN'), ('Advisor', 'NOUN'), ('Director', 'NOUN'), ('of', 'ADP'), ('Microsoft', 'PROPN'), ('Corporation', 'PROPN'), ('a', 'DET'), ('cofounder', 'NOUN'), ('served', 'VERB'), ('as', 'ADP'), ('Chairman', 'PROPN'), ('from', 'ADP'), ('our', 'PRON'), ('incorporation', 'NOUN'), ('in', 'ADP'), ('1981', 'NUM'), ('until', 'ADP'), ('2014', 'NUM'), ('He', 'PRON'), ('currently', 'ADV'), ('acts', 'VERB'), ('Technical', 'ADJ'), ('to', 'ADP'), ('Nadella', 'NUM'), ('on', 'ADP'), ('key', 'ADJ'), ('development', 'NOUN'), ('projects', 'NOUN'), ('retired', 'VERB'), ('an', 'DET'), ('employee', 'NOUN'), ('2008', 'NUM'), ('Chief', 'NOUN'), ('Software', 'PROPN'), ('Architect', 'PROPN'), ('2000', 'NUM'), ('2006', 'NUM'), ('when', 'ADV'), ('he', 'PRON'), ('announced', 'VERB'), ('his', 'PRON'), ('two', 'NUM'), ('-', 'PUNCT'), ('year', 'NOUN'), ('plan', 'NOUN'), ('transition', 'VERB'), ('out', 'ADP'), ('day', 'NOUN'), ('full', 'ADJ'), ('time', 'NOUN'), ('role', 'NOUN'), ('Executive', 'PROPN'), ('Officer', 'PROPN'), ('resigned', 'VERB'), ('assumed', 'VERB'), ('the', 'DET'), ('position', 'NOUN'), ('As', 'ADP'), ('co', 'PROPN'), ('chair', 'NOUN'), ('Bill', 'NOUN'), ('&', 'CONJ'), ('Melinda', 'PROPN'), ('Foundation', 'PROPN'), ('shapes', 'NOUN'), ('approves', 'VERB'), ('grant', 'NOUN'), ('making', 'VERB'), ('strategies', 'NOUN'), ('advocates', 'NOUN'), ('for', 'ADP'), ('foundation’s', 'NUM'), ('issues', 'NOUN'), ('helps', 'VERB'), ('set', 'VERB'), ('overall', 'ADJ'), ('direction', 'NOUN'), ('organization', 'NOUN'), ('founder', 'NOUN'), ('’', 'NUM'), ('foresight', 'NOUN'), ('vision', 'NOUN'), ('personal', 'ADJ'), ('computing', 'NOUN'), ('have', 'AUX'), ('been', 'VERB'), ('central', 'ADJ'), ('success', 'NOUN'), ('software', 'NOUN'), ('industry', 'NOUN'), ('has', 'VERB'), ('unparalleled', 'ADJ'), ('knowledge', 'NOUN'), ('Company’s', 'NUM'), ('history', 'NOUN'), ('technologies', 'NOUN'), ('Company', 'NOUN'), ('its', 'PRON'), ('grew', 'VERB'), ('fledgling', 'ADJ'), ('business', 'NOUN'), ('into', 'ADP'), ('world’s', 'NUM'), ('leading', 'VERB'), ('company', 'NOUN'), ('process', 'NOUN'), ('creating', 'VERB'), ('one', 'NUM'), ('most', 'ADV'), ('prolific', 'ADJ'), ('sources', 'NOUN'), ('innovation', 'NOUN'), ('powerful', 'ADJ'), ('brands', 'NOUN'), ('through', 'ADP'), ('motion', 'NOUN'), ('technological', 'ADJ'), ('strategic', 'ADJ'), ('programs', 'NOUN'), ('that', 'DET'), ('are', 'VERB'), ('core', 'NOUN'), ('part', 'NOUN'), ('continues', 'VERB'), ('provide', 'VERB'), ('technical', 'ADJ'), ('input', 'NOUN'), ('evolution', 'NOUN'), ('productivity', 'NOUN'), ('platform', 'NOUN'), ('mobile', 'NOUN'), ('first', 'ADJ'), ('cloud', 'NOUN'), ('world', 'NOUN'), ('His', 'PRON'), ('work', 'NOUN'), ('overseeing', 'VERB'), ('provides', 'VERB'), ('global', 'ADJ'), ('insights', 'NOUN'), ('relevant', 'ADJ'), ('current', 'ADJ'), ('future', 'ADJ'), ('opportunities', 'NOUN'), ('keen', 'ADJ'), ('appreciation', 'NOUN'), ('stakeholder', 'ADJ'), ('interests', 'NOUN')]
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['word','type'])
data[(data.type=='NOUN') | (data.type=='PROPN')]
```

addendum for the comments section:

You have the ability to find out stuff about your data like.

```
data.groupby(data.type).count()

       word
type
ADJ      20
ADP      12
ADV       3
AUX       1
CONJ      2
DET       4
NOUN     56
NUM      13
PRON      6
PROPN    16
PUNCT     3
VERB     22
```

You can convert it back to python datatypes after the crunching is finished.

```
list(data[(data.type=='NOUN') | (data.type=='PROPN')].word)
```

Comment: I did not knowed that this can be done with pandas. Could you provide more examples of how to use pandas for such task?. THANK YOU VERY MUCH.

Answer (score 1):

Like so?

```
thing_list = []
for i, x in enumerate(data):
    if x[0] == "of":
        if (data[i-1][1] == "NOUN") and (data[i+1][1] == "PROPN"):
            thing_list.append(data[i-1:i+2])
```

Comment: I got this: `[[('Director', 'NOUN'), ('of', 'ADP')]]` which is wrong.

Comment: Oops, mixed up some indicies. I think it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Took a crack at this just because it seemed interesting. If you're willing to put up with a soup of `map`s, `lambda`s and `filter`s this appears to work:

```
matches = map(
    lambda _: (data[_ - 1], data[_], data[_ + 1]),
    filter(
        lambda _: data[_ - 1][1] == "NOUN" and data[_ + 1][1] == "PROPN",
        map(
            lambda _: _[0],
            filter(
                lambda _: _[1][0] == "of",
                enumerate(data)
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: If you need a `lambda` to use `map` or `filter`, don't use `map` or `filter`. It's slower, less readable, less obvious, and usually less concise than equivalent listcomps or genexprs.

Answer (score 1):

```
def trioPattern( trioCols, trioElements):
    """trioCols = (Use element 0 or 1 of the first pair, 0 or 1 of the second pair, 0 or 1 of the third pair)
       trioElements = (Phrase of the first element, Phrase of the second element, Phrase of the third element)"""

    data = [('Mr', 'PROPN'), ('.', 'PUNCT'), ('William', 'PROPN'), ('Henry', 'PROPN'), ('Gates', 'PROPN'), (',', 'PUNCT'), ('III', 'NUM'), ('is', 'VERB'), ('Founder', 'PROPN'), ('and', 'CONJ'), ('Technology', 'PROPN'), ('Advisor', 'NOUN'), ('Director', 'NOUN'), ('of', 'ADP'), ('Microsoft', 'PROPN'), ('Corporation', 'PROPN'), ('a', 'DET'), ('cofounder', 'NOUN'), ('served', 'VERB'), ('as', 'ADP'), ('Chairman', 'PROPN'), ('from', 'ADP'), ('our', 'PRON'), ('incorporation', 'NOUN'), ('in', 'ADP'), ('1981', 'NUM'), ('until', 'ADP'), ('2014', 'NUM'), ('He', 'PRON'), ('currently', 'ADV'), ('acts', 'VERB'), ('Technical', 'ADJ'), ('to', 'ADP'), ('Nadella', 'NUM'), ('on', 'ADP'), ('key', 'ADJ'), ('development', 'NOUN'), ('projects', 'NOUN'), ('retired', 'VERB'), ('an', 'DET'), ('employee', 'NOUN'), ('2008', 'NUM'), ('Chief', 'NOUN'), ('Software', 'PROPN'), ('Architect', 'PROPN'), ('2000', 'NUM'), ('2006', 'NUM'), ('when', 'ADV'), ('he', 'PRON'), ('announced', 'VERB'), ('his', 'PRON'), ('two', 'NUM'), ('-', 'PUNCT'), ('year', 'NOUN'), ('plan', 'NOUN'), ('transition', 'VERB'), ('out', 'ADP'), ('day', 'NOUN'), ('full', 'ADJ'), ('time', 'NOUN'), ('role', 'NOUN'), ('Executive', 'PROPN'), ('Officer', 'PROPN'), ('resigned', 'VERB'), ('assumed', 'VERB'), ('the', 'DET'), ('position', 'NOUN'), ('As', 'ADP'), ('co', 'PROPN'), ('chair', 'NOUN'), ('Bill', 'NOUN'), ('&', 'CONJ'), ('Melinda', 'PROPN'), ('Foundation', 'PROPN'), ('shapes', 'NOUN'), ('approves', 'VERB'), ('grant', 'NOUN'), ('making', 'VERB'), ('strategies', 'NOUN'), ('advocates', 'NOUN'), ('for', 'ADP'), ('foundation’s', 'NUM'), ('issues', 'NOUN'), ('helps', 'VERB'), ('set', 'VERB'), ('overall', 'ADJ'), ('direction', 'NOUN'), ('organization', 'NOUN'), ('founder', 'NOUN'), ('’', 'NUM'), ('foresight', 'NOUN'), ('vision', 'NOUN'), ('personal', 'ADJ'), ('computing', 'NOUN'), ('have', 'AUX'), ('been', 'VERB'), ('central', 'ADJ'), ('success', 'NOUN'), ('software', 'NOUN'), ('industry', 'NOUN'), ('has', 'VERB'), ('unparalleled', 'ADJ'), ('knowledge', 'NOUN'), ('Company’s', 'NUM'), ('history', 'NOUN'), ('technologies', 'NOUN'), ('Company', 'NOUN'), ('its', 'PRON'), ('grew', 'VERB'), ('fledgling', 'ADJ'), ('business', 'NOUN'), ('into', 'ADP'), ('world’s', 'NUM'), ('leading', 'VERB'), ('company', 'NOUN'), ('process', 'NOUN'), ('creating', 'VERB'), ('one', 'NUM'), ('most', 'ADV'), ('prolific', 'ADJ'), ('sources', 'NOUN'), ('innovation', 'NOUN'), ('powerful', 'ADJ'), ('brands', 'NOUN'), ('through', 'ADP'), ('motion', 'NOUN'), ('technological', 'ADJ'), ('strategic', 'ADJ'), ('programs', 'NOUN'), ('that', 'DET'), ('are', 'VERB'), ('core', 'NOUN'), ('part', 'NOUN'), ('continues', 'VERB'), ('provide', 'VERB'), ('technical', 'ADJ'), ('input', 'NOUN'), ('evolution', 'NOUN'), ('productivity', 'NOUN'), ('platform', 'NOUN'), ('mobile', 'NOUN'), ('first', 'ADJ'), ('cloud', 'NOUN'), ('world', 'NOUN'), ('His', 'PRON'), ('work', 'NOUN'), ('overseeing', 'VERB'), ('provides', 'VERB'), ('global', 'ADJ'), ('insights', 'NOUN'), ('relevant', 'ADJ'), ('current', 'ADJ'), ('future', 'ADJ'), ('opportunities', 'NOUN'), ('keen', 'ADJ'), ('appreciation', 'NOUN'), ('stakeholder', 'ADJ'), ('interests', 'NOUN')]

    #Elements of the triple pattern
    ColE1, ColE2, ColE3 = trioCols
    trios = dict([( (data[e][ColE1], data[e+1][ColE2], data[e+2][ColE3]), (data[e], data[e+1], data[e+2])) for e in range(0, len(data)-2)])

    #Triple pattern phrases
    E1, E2, E3 = trioElements
    if trios.has_key((E1, E2, E3)):
        return trios[(E1, E2, E3)]
    else:
        return "Not found"
```

Examples:

trioPattern( (1,0,1), ("NOUN", "of", "PROPN") )

```
(('Director', 'NOUN'), ('of', 'ADP'), ('Microsoft', 'PROPN'))
```

trioPattern( (0,1,1), ("world’s", "VERB", "NOUN") )

```
(('world’s', 'NUM'), ('leading', 'VERB'), ('company', 'NOUN'))
```